# How to make a changes Log of a orders system

Tags: database, logging, data-structures

I've seen stackoverflow's question changes log and is very rich;

i have a system that register product Orders but that orders change very often
What is the database structure to save and have access to an order and see the order versions?

My tables are:

`Clients`
`Orders`
`Articles_Order`
in Articles_Orders is where the order code, the product code and the quantity is stored and is what changes (adding products etc)
or where i can find a example of that?

Comment: Usually you'd set these up either in the database layer of your application or as a trigger on the db server itself.  The real answer is going to very on exactly what information you are trying to retain.  For example you could have another table with the same fields plus a change datetime where 'old' entries are added, or you could have a table that lists each changed field in a separate record.

Comment: what changes is the products and the quantity of these and is the information i want to log

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how do to this using update triggers [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php).  Following is a copy/paste snippet of that page:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    ( order_id number(5),
      quantity number(4),
  cost_per_item number(6,2),
  total_cost number(8,2)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON orders
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN

   -- Find username of person performing UPDATE into table
   SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO orders_audit
   ( order_id,
     quantity_before,
     quantity_after,
     username )
   VALUES
   ( :new.order_id,
     :old.quantity,
     :new.quantity,
     v_username );

END;
```